# Is there a way to recover my system while rebooting

Tags: data-recovery

I want to make a recover mechanism for my Ubuntu, meaning that no matter how I change my system while working, if I reboot, the system will always be reset to the original state. For example, I created and remove some files, but after rebooting, the created files should have been removed and the removed files should have been back.

Is there such a tool?

Comment: Something like this? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316018/how-to-use-overlayfs-to-protect-the-root-filesystem

Comment: on every reboot? you could use the ubuntu Live CD as your daily driver then.

Comment: I have read in the past of freezing/sandboxing(not right words) system, but not sure if it was for windows or linux.  A live CD/USB would do what you want, losing changes every reboot, but will also include any updates or changes you do want to keep.

Comment: I think the data-recovery tag is not appropriate for this question. That's about recovering lost data. This question is not about recovering anything, but simply about impersistence.

Comment: Overlayroot is probably what you are looking for. [Here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/10/protecting-ubuntu-root-filesystem/) is a short introduction.